# Use "the USE [Database]" statement dynamically inside a SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I've created a stored procedure where I want to pass the @DB through a USE command. I know I can define dynamically the correct path for the table with the name of the DB (e.g. ... '+ @DB +' .dbo.tAnalysisResult' )  but I have several inner joins with many tables on the same database so I'd like to define the DB only once at the beginning.
Any help will be highly appreciated. Below my query which currently doesn't work:

```
USE [DB_Research]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].sp_test1 @DB VARCHAR(300), @OUTCOME INT OUTPUT
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

EXECUTE ('USE' + @DB)

BEGIN TRY
SELECT @OUTCOME = (select SUM(ResultSID) from tAnalysisResult)

END TRY BEGIN CATCH

-- If error encountered, display it
SELECT @OUTCOME = '0, line: ' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ', msg:' + ERROR_MESSAGE()

END CATCH
SET NOCOUNT OFF

-- Execute the stored procedure
declare @OUTCOME INT
exec sp_test1  'Loss_DB', @OUTCOME OUTPUT
Print(@OUTCOME)
```

Comment: Create a string and then `execute` it, like you did with many others in the procedure? :)

Comment: Unfortunately I tried already but didn't work.

Comment: `The following statements cannot be used anywhere in the body of a stored procedure. USE database_name`. See [CREATE PROCEDURE (Transact-SQL :: Limitations and Restrictions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926%28v=sql.120%29.aspx#Anchor_5).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from dbname..schemaname.tablename
```